# Chrome Browser in Android Emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome, emulation, appium

I have to run a automate test on chrome browser in android emulator with Api level 19 and android version 4.4.2 to test by web application.

I run the test with Appium.

I could not find the compact-able versions of Chrome browser for my environment. the chrome 40 to 47 gets crashed in emulator during the browser launch.

```
Appium - 1.4.16.1 
Api level - 19
Android version - 4.4.2
```

Can some one help me in getting the correct chrome apk version?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the default browser in the emulator to avoid problem of compatibility between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Enable storage permission for chrome from Settings->Apps->Chrome->Permission->Storage